# how to remove clipping plane in THREE js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera

I want to remove clipping planes in THREE js but I can't seem to find any information on how to do this. What I found is that orthographic camera can have negative value for near clipping plane.

If I put negative value in near clipping plane of perspective camera, it doesn't throw an error but doesn't show any objects.

I draw relatively huge objects and the near clipping plane is very frustrating when I try to explore them as they disapear completely if they are behind the camera even if most of the object should still be visible, is there a way to remove it so my objects always gets drawn?

here is the camera values I use:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, size.x/size.y, 0.1, 1000);
```

When I move, I move the camera instead of *all* the objects relative to a fixed camera, I guessed it would be more performent, but I don't think it matters for my problem.

All of the objects have position (0, 0, 0) but can have part extending up to 10-15 units away from their position

Comment: "I draw relatively huge objects and the near clipping plane is very frustrating when I try to explore them as they disapear completely if they are behind the camera even if most of the object should still be visible," - this is probably because of face culling. The near plane does only clip the part of the object which is behind the near plane. Theoretically, you can increase the distance to the far plane to any amount, but not in practice, because the accuracy of the depth buffer is limited.

Comment: @Rabbid76 after some research on face culling, it was because I draw my objects dynamically and I wasn't updating the bounding sphere.

Comment: You can also set .frustumCulled to false on custom objects if you want to force them to render at all times, regardless of visibility.